# Active Directory remotely

Tags: server, active-directory, fault

I have done several research on the subject but I still remain unanswered.
I wonder if these possible to create an ActiveDirectory server and connected it from a computer that is not under the same local network.
If these possible would you have a URL to tell me the steps or possibilities.
No answer is currently found on StackOverFlow.

Comment: Questions on professional server- or networking-related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools. You may be able to get help on `Server Fault`.

Comment: This flag does not exist

Comment: You can delete your question from here, and better repost there. BTW, your question sounds too broad. Please share your research too when you ask a new question! Good Luck.